# In Vim's NERDTree, is there a way to open a file/dir using the space key or tab key?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Currently the only way to open the file or directory currently underneath your cursor is to type `o`.  Is there a way to also map this to space or tab?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
let NERDTreeMapActivateNode='<space>'
```

should work fine. For more information see `:h NERDTreeMappings`.